# Finding the private key: Attack against El Gamal

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, cryptography

El Gamal encryption involves picking $(p,g,b)$ which is our public key. We compute $b=a^x$ $mod$ $p$. Here, $x$ is the private key which we don't know. What are some efficient and strong algorithms today used to finding this $x$? I am currently dealing with numbers such as $b=42-49$ digits long and $p=43-50$. So $b$ is anywhere between 42 and 49 digits. Does anyone know of any program and some attacks to finding this $x$ using our given information? I am looking for a program in Maple but I will take the algorithm if anyone knows of any.

Comment: With the equation you show, it doesn't make sense for $b$ to be longer than $p$.

Comment: Your right, it was a mistake.

Comment: Cross-posted on [crypto.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/12384/attacks-against-el-gamal-private-key) (and security.SE and stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0):

As you are working with numbers of around 160 bits, the index calculus method is not going to be quick enough, I think. So you will need the number field sieve method, I think. A link to an implementation of that method is [here](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cvs/dlog/), with a thesis explaining the different methods involved. You'll need the dlog-nfs code.